# Entity Framework, get ConcurrencyMode of Properties from MetadataWorkspace, how?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Given an Entity Type, how to discover the ConcurrencyMode of a Property of that Entity Type at runtime by introspecting the MetadataWorkspace of CSpace?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TypeUsage.Facets](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6d2561f0-d650-41ce-b43d-822368b3833d)

```
[EntityContext] etContext = new [EntityContext]();
var csdl = etContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSpace);
var entity = csdl.GetItems<EntityType>().Where(e => e.Name = [EntityType]).SingleOrDefault();
var edmProperty = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.Name == [PropertyName]).SingleOrDefault();
var mode = edmProperty.TypeUsage.Facets.Where(f => f.Name ==     "ConcurrencyMode").SingleOrDefault();
```